# How to transition different background colors with a delay effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a sequence of transitions/animations, so therefor this particular example I need to have a javascript solution and not a css keyframe solution.

I am using delays for a lot of my different sequences and I am trying to do the same with a new background color, but for some reason using the `addClass` function is not working for me.

Why is this not  working for me?

```js
//$(".blue").delay(2500).addClass("green-fill");
$(".green-fill").delay(2500).addClass("green-fill");
```

```css
.blue {
 background-color: #0085A1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.green-fill {
 display: none;
 background: green;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
   <div class="green-fill">
   Hello
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're adding the green fill class to an element that already has it. That's clearly not right.

Comment: Well, if I do this... https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vUJEKQ2BAM   ... it still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.green-fill {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;

    transition:background-color 1s;
}
.green-fill.blue{
    background-color:#00f;
}
```

jQuery

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".green-fill").addClass("blue");
},2500);

// That's why css keyframes are better...
// For smooth ease back : the trick is to copy the color being rendered, then remove class, and then finally remove the inline generated code.

setTimeout(function(){
    var $gb = $(".green-fill");
    var color = $gb.css("background-color");
    $gb.css("background-color",color).removeClass("blue").css("background-color","");

  },5000);
```

Comment: What would this do? `.green-fill.blue{`

Comment: @Paul if you don't .blue class has defined the new color, you want to transition into. .green-fill.blue will give priority to the color inside .blue class. So whenever there will a blue class on green-fill element, it will give priority to blue color.

Comment: Didn't help. I just want the green background to delay for the duration and then show up over the blue.

Comment: Updated the code. Delay only works on animations like fadeOut, animate. and Animate don't animate the background color. Hence, setTimout, and transition.

Comment: Other things are, making and element display none, and and showing that element again don't trigger transitions. So try doing, visibility hidden for elements having transitions.

Comment: Awesome. That helped. Do you know if there is a way to ease out the green-fill div when I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the class "green-fill" to the exact same class "green-fill". Therefore the class is imediatly applied to the div. Change the class of  to something else or give it an id (like I did in the example below).

Javascript:

```
//$(".blue").delay(2500).addClass("green-fill");
$("#fill-it").delay(2500).addClass("green-fill");
```

Markup:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
   <div id="fill-it">
   Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS can stay the same.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you wrap the JS-Function in a event handler, so it gets triggered? Try wrapping it in something like `$(document).ready(function() { .... })`